# Nexus: Gradle plugin org.unbroken-dome.test-sets not found

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We have a private Nexus and we are getting everything except for this gradle plugin.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.unbroken-dome.test-sets' version '1.2.0'
}
```

**setting.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
  resolutionStrategy {
      eachPlugin {
         if (requested.id.namespace == 'org.unbroken-dome.gradle-plugins') {
          useModule('org.unbroken-dome.gradle-plugins:gradle-testsets-plugin:1.5.0')
        }
      }
  }
  repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://someurl.com/repository/MavenRepoGroup/'
            credentials {
                username 'username'
                password 'password'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever, I try to build I get following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.unbroken-dome.test-sets', version: '1.2.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- maven(http://someurl.com/repository/MavenRepoGroup/) (Could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.unbroken-dome.test-sets:org.unbroken-dome.test-sets.gradle.plugin:1.2.0')
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that by configuring your custom `repositories` in `settings.gradle` you've overridden the default one. Try adding it back like

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url 'http://someurl.com/repository/MavenRepoGroup/'
            credentials {
                username 'username'
                password 'password'
            }
        }
    }
    …
}
```

Comment: As I understand, `gradlePluginPortal()` will not use the maven repository I have provided which isn't an option. Can't skip the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `useModule` condition is not aligned with the plugin id.
You have: `if (requested.id.namespace == 'org.unbroken-dome.gradle-plugins')` vs. `id 'org.unbroken-dome.test-sets'` where the part after `org.unbroken-dome.` is different.